# Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY' how to fix?

Tags: mysql, vue.js, post, knex.js

I do it with knex and the fronted is done with vue js. Everthing works but the post not and when i put something in the form it comes Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY' how can i fix that?

I do it with knex and the fronted is done with vue js. Everthing works but the post not and when i put something in the form it comes Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY' how can i fix that?

```
exports.up = function(knex) {
  return knex.schema.createTable('series', function(table) {
    table.increments('id').unsigned().primary()
    table.string('text').notNullable()
    table.enum('rating', ['good', 'not bad', 'bad']).defaultTo('not bad')
    table.string('comment').notNullable()
  })
};

exports.down = function(knex) {
  return knex.schema.dropTableIfExists('series')
};
```

The frontend

```
template>
  <div class="Series">
    <h2>Table</h2> 
        <table id="tabelle" border="1">
            <!-- Header -->
            <tr>
                <th>text</th>
                <th>rating</th>
                <th>comment</th>
                <th>action</th>
            </tr>
            <!-- series List -->
            <tr v-for="series in series" :key="series.id">
                <td> {{series.text}}</td>
                <td>{{series.rating}}</td>
                <td>{{series.comment}}</td>
                <td><button @click="removeData(series.id)">Löschen</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <input type="text" name="text" v-model="series.text"> <br>
          <select name="rating" v-model="series.rating">
                <option>good</option>
                <option>not bad</option>
                <option>bad</option>
          </select><br>
          <input type="text" name="comment" v-model="series.comment"> <br>
          <button @click="postData" >Post</button>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: 'Series',
  data() {
    return {
      series: {},
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getData(){
      axios.get('/api/series').then((response) =>{
        console.log(response.data);
        this.series = response.data;
       })
      .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
       });
    },
    postData(){
      axios.post('/api/serie/create', this.series)
      .then((result) => {
          console.warn(result)
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    },
    removeData(id){
      axios.delete('/api/serie/delete/'+id).then(()=>{
        this.getData();
      })
    }
  },
  mounted() {
      this.getData()
  },

  
}
</script>
```

endpoints

```
app.post('/api/serie/create', (req,res)=> {
  console.log("create");
  console.log(req.body);
  let serie = req.body
  knex('series').insert(serie)
    .then(results => res.json(results))
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err.sqlMessage)
      res.status(500)
      res.json(err.sqlMessage)
    }) 
})
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhAfn.png)

Comment: It's while trying to display your data that this error occurs ?

Comment: yes everytime when i try to put something in the input to post

Comment: I have voted to close this question, because the error shown is an sql error, but while a migration script of some sort and the frontend is shown, no actual endpoint code is shown.

Answer (score 0):

This error tells you like what each time you want to save in your database, the primary key is duplicated because your "primary key column" doesn't increment. Check that your  "primary key column " is auto-incrementing. If not, or modify to auto-increment or increment it manually.

Comment: I did in MySql Workbench and its still didnt work.